# attrs readonly not working in group, page, notebook tags

Tags: xml, odoo, readonly

how to solution this issue?

```
    <xpath expr="//sheet/notebook" position="attributes">
                        <attribute name="attrs">{'readonly': [('gender', '==', False)]}</attribute>
  </xpath>
```

Please, help? I need any solution.

Answer (score 1):

The reason is that readonly attribute are intended for editable widgets. It's not something that DOM node childs could inherit from parents. You could associate those readonly attributes directly to fields